# Is functions composition in spring-cloud-function / spring-cloud-stream pass by value, or is it reusing the integration in between

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

Hi don't understand and it is not described in the documentation of either "`spring-cloud-function`" or "`spring-cloud-stream`". If I have two functions "`Uppercase`" and "`reverse`".
Lets say I have a source queue - "`uppercase-source`" input to "`Uppercase`" function which does output to "`uppercase-output`".
And then "uppercase-output" is source to "`reverse`" function which outputs to "`reverse-output`".

If I perform a function composition the following way:

```
--spring.cloud.function.definition=uppercase|reverse
```

Wil the resulting function use pass by value in between "uppercase" and "reverse", or will the resulting function still uses the queues/topics in between this would say "uppercase-output"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested it.Spring cloud stream uses the integration in between the functions when performing composition.